# TextReader and peek next line

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I read a data from a text file using `TextReader`

```
TextReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string line;
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
 {
   //.......
 }
```

Sometimes I need to peek next line (**or a few next lines**) from reader.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: Updated to allow any number of peeks:

```
public class PeekingStreamReader : StreamReader
{
    private Queue<string> _peeks;

    public PeekingStreamReader(Stream stream) : base(stream)
    {
        _peeks = new Queue<string>();   
    }

    public override string ReadLine()
    {
        if (_peeks.Count > 0)
        {
            var nextLine = _peeks.Dequeue();
            return nextLine;
        }
        return base.ReadLine();
    }

    public string PeekReadLine()
    {
        var nextLine = ReadLine();
        _peeks.Enqueue(nextLine);
        return nextLine;
    }
}
```

Comment: The same as I saw above. It's not going to help me either.

Comment: @AlanDert I've updated my sample to use a `Queue<string>` to allow any number of peeks.

Comment: +1 for inheriting from `StreamReader` which is a concrete class, rather than `TextReader` which is an abstract class (I just checked, as I knew something was bothering me).

Comment: @armen.shimoon, Sorry, but peeking doesn't mean changing the state of reader. Your approach looks like peeking but it actually doesn't peek, it reads them and it changes the state of reader.

Comment: Handy, but there's a problem with `EndOfStream`, since it needs to check both the `EndOfStream ` property and that there's no peeked lines. Unfortunately you can't override the base property but you can add your own function easily enough.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this yourself; however, it is not that difficult:

```
public class PeekTextReader {
    string lastLine;
    private readonly TextReader reader;
    public PeekTextReader(TextReader reader) {
        this.reader = reader;
    }
    public string Peek() {
        return lastLine ?? (lastLine = reader.ReadLine());
    }
    public string ReadLine() {
        string res;
        if (lastLine != null) {
            res = lastLine;
            lastLine = null;
        } else {
            res = reader.ReadLine();
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

Note that peeking once will keep the line locked in until you do a full `ReadLine`.

Comment: But it reads a line, it doesn't peek it. What if I want to peek several lines? Your code keeps only one last line.

Comment: @AlanDert Not as far as the callers of the `ReadLine` should know: to them, a call to `Peek` does not look like a read, because the next call to `ReadLine` will return the picked line back to you. In other words, the peeked line does not get *consumed*.

Comment: Edge cases -- what happens if the client calls `Peek` when the last physical line has already been read?  Its these details that are the killer in robust utility classes.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ The call would nicely return `null` in case that the `Peek` gets called at the last line - the same thing the `ReadLine` should return.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, it actually reads the lines, it doesn't peek them. How does it peek them if it uses ReadLine() method? It even doesn't use Peek().

Comment: @alanDert - You criticize the responder for only peeking ahead one line, but that is what you asked for.  If you are looking for a general n-lookahead buffer, then that is what you would need to implement.  In these cases, however, you are probably better structuring your program with an n-line memory, rather than an n-line lookahead, which is the essentially the same thing theoretically, but easier to implement practically due to EOF conditions.   The only place I know where 1-symbol lookahead is normally used is recursive decent parsers.

Comment: @AlanDert There is absolutely no point in using the `Peek` of the internal `TextReader` - it gives you only one character, and you need the entire line. You use `PeekTextReader` in place of `TextReader`, so from your point of view a `Peek` is a peek, not a read. The internal `TextReader` gets read when you `Peek`, but that is *not* the stream from which your program reads.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Sorry, you are quite right -- I had just checked the API docs and was coming back to update, and this is one case where the Microsoft API is friendlier than average.  My only defense is I have programmed in way, way too many platforms and environments over the years, and this is a common gotcha that .NET doesn't have :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - `TextReader` is abstract, probably need to inherit from `StreamReader` or use composition (which is what I would do in this case, although I am hard pressed to think of a case where that would matter here.

Comment: +1. I would not inherit from actual reader (unless you are willing to provide correct implemetation of other read methods, potentially including async versions). The only thing I'd add is `IDisposable` to close inner reader.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reliable way to move reading location backward in text readers. You can try to seek underlying stream but it may not be possible (if stream does not supprt seek) or may not give results you want if any kind of caching happens inside reader.

The most realiable approach would be to remember the last line, you may consider creating custom class that will extend reader with PeekString functionality... But it may be hard to implement properly if you will need to re-read that string using other reader methods.

Comment: I'd rather use something like `while (not end of line) str += reader.Peek()`. Does it matter?

Answer (score 0):

You can read all the lines from the file (ReadAllLines), then you can easily operate on them. But look at the size of the file, that you could use too much memory.